# how can i solve this issue?

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

```
'\env\Scripts\activate.bat : The term '\env\Scripts\activate.bat' 
is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,  
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path  
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.       
At line:1 char:1 \env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

> CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (\env\Scripts\activ
> ate.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException'

Comment: In which directory do you execute this command? What is the complete command？

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a few assumptions, if they're wrong you can let me know.
You are on windows (because you are running a batch file) and you are running this in vs code's terminal.

Try just typing `env\Scripts\activate`.

This is because .bat files run in the windows command prompt, but vs code's terminal is PowerShell which doesn't recognize batch files (PowerShell uses .ps1 files).